# Xcos superblock throws an unusual error

Tags: scilab, modelica, xcos

I've been trying to create a set of super blocks using Electrical blocks & even with a very simple circuit, Xcos throws the error "The number of equations doesn't match the number of variables".

My circuit consists of a 3 phase supply connected to a 3 phase load. In the form below, it works just fine. No errors whatsoever. Note that I haven't even added the scope blocks yet.
[image: No error diagram]

However, the moment I move those resistors to a superblock,
[image: Error diagram]

I start getting the following error -
[image: Error msg]

Here's the link to the [Zcos file](https://ufile.io/7278g)

Could someone please throw some light on what's going on here?

Comment: I downloaded Scilab and loaded your example. I couldn't get the error you had indicated but got other ones. The issue for me was I could never actually get to the code of the model to trouble shoot. Highly recommend trying to reproduce your model in OpenModelica so you can look at the code directly.

Comment: Which version of Scilab did you use? I tried it on 2 different PCs with both 5.5.2 & 6.0.1 (the latest) and got the exact same error.

Comment: 6.0.1 on windows. The file you linked when opened wouldn't simulate at all. Just gave some sort of cryptic "Invalid" error on the console screen. I deleted the top resistor and put it back. The thing seemed to simulate but there were never any results and the error you had didn't show up. Very confusing.

Comment: I didn't add any scope blocks to keep things simple, so you won't get any results. That was expected. Could you load your file somewhere & share a link to it? Also, when you said you deleted the top resistor, did you do this inside the superblock?

Comment: http://dropcanvas.com/nrnuh - I put the original (orig) and modified (mod) files at that link. No I deleted and re-added the top resistor (the component between the voltage source and superblock).